# I'm using an aggregate function from mongodb, the problem is that I need only one information in my console

Tags: javascript, mongodb, object

In my case I only want get a number to use it. This is my schema:

```
const personaSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    nombre:String,
    direccion: String,
    dineroRecibido: Number,
    fecha: String
},{versionKey: false})
```

this is my aggregate function:

```
const mostrarSumaDinerosPorDia = async (fecha) =>{
    const sumaDineroHoy = await PersonaModel.aggregate(
      [
          {$match:{fecha:fecha}},
          {$group:{_id:'$fecha'   ,total:{$sum:'$dineroRecibido'}}}
      ]  
    
    )
   
    console.log(sumaDineroHoy)
}
```

and this is my answer console:

```
[ { _id: '24 de diciembre del 2021', total: 10000 } ]
```

I only want get 10000, no more.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your aggregation pipeline `{ $project: { "_id": 0 } }`

More info on `$project` here: [$project MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/)

Comment: I am still getting problems with this!!!! Help Please 

Comment: could you share your refactored query?